# Plural em “tem” com sentido de “há”

Tags: haver

No Brasil é muito comum usar “tem” no sentido de existir (em vez de ser no sentido de posse), embora na escola se ensine que nessa situação deve-se usar “há”.

O verbo haver nesse caso é impessoal (isso também é enfatizado na escola e nas gramáticas de português), portanto se diz: “há muitas coisas”, “houve vários transtornos”, “haverá diversas discussões” (e não hão/houveram/haverão).

Até aí, tudo bem. Mas apesar do que a escola prega e para o desprazer dos gramáticos, o uso de “tem” acaba fazendo parte da língua cotidiana e eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma recomendação da sua forma de uso — impessoal como o “há” ou pessoal como o próprio verbo ter em outras situações — ou se a gramática tradicional se abstém totalmente neste caso.

Por exemplo:
“Tinha muitas coisas lá” ou “tinham muitas coisas lá”?
“Teve vários transtornos” ou “Tiveram vários transtornos”?

Por analogia com o verbo haver, e também por intuição/costume, acho que o correto é manter o verbo no singular, por ser impessoal. Nas frases acima “muitas coisas” e “vários transtornos” são objetos e não sujeito.

Mas também tenho ouvido muitas pessoas usarem o plural, o que me parece um caso de hipercorreção, tentando fazer mais concordâncias verbais (ou nominais) do que o necessário. Isso sempre me soa bem errado, mas como o que estudei só trata do verbo haver, fico em dúvida. Algum autor/professor/etc. já se manifestou sobre isso?

Comment: Achei somente alguns sites:
http://dicasdiariasdeportugues.com.br/a-concordancia-do-verbo-ter-no-sentido-de-existir/
http://soumaisenem.com.br/redacao/lingua-e-linguagem/o-uso-dos-verbos-ter-haver-e-existir

Comment: Já é mais do que eu achei da última vez que pesquisei. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Tem* vários sites que recomendam a conjugação só na terceira pessoa do singular, por exemplo, [Não tropece na língua 289](http://www.linguabrasil.com.br/img/colunas/Coluna_N289_2011-09-07.pdf) e [046](http://www.linguabrasil.com.br/img/colunas/Coluna_N046_2012-10-10.pdf) (ênfase minha):

> ***Tem mulheres*** que adoram “rodar a baiana”.
>
> “***Tem dias*** que a gente se sente como quem partiu ou morreu...” [(Chico Buarque, *Roda Viva*)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1M7cgm6Yqk)

Não encontrei nenhum site que recomendasse ou aceitasse o contrário. Nenhum destes sites cita qualquer gramático famoso. O argumento que eles apresentam é o mesmo que tu avanças. Nestes casos a oração não tem sujeito. Nos exemplos acima, *mulheres* e *dias* é o objeto direto do verbo e não o seu sujeito. Logo o verbo flexiona sempre na terceira pessoa do singular.

Exceto para o verbo *ser*, esta é a regra seguida nas orações sem sujeito na *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (2014, p. 168-70)  não só para o verbo *haver*, mas também para o *fazer* e *ir* (ênfase minha):

> Na sala ***havia ainda três quadros*** do pintor (Fernando Namora, *Domingo à Tarde*, 1975).
>
> ***Faz hoje oito dias*** que comecei (Augusto Abelaira, *Bolor*, 1974).
>
> ***Vai para uns quinze anos*** que escrevi uma crónica... (Manuel Bandeira, *Poesia e prosa*, 1958).

A *Gramática* observa então (p. 169):

> Na linguagem coloquial do Brasil é corrente o emprego do verbo *ter* como impessoal, à semelhança de *haver*. Escritores modernos ― e alguns dos maiores ― não têm duvidado em alçar a construção à língua literária.

A *Gramática* apresenta alguns exemplos, mas o objeto direto é em todos singular, logo não dá para tirar as teimas. Mas o *à semelhança de haver* indica que eles estão a pensar na conjugação exclusivamente na terceira pessoa no singular.

Parece no entanto haver pessoas que acham mais natural a conjugação de acordo com o número do objeto direto. Vejam no [dicas diárias do português](http://dicasdiariasdeportugues.com.br/a-concordancia-do-verbo-ter-no-sentido-de-existir/), um dos sites que recomenda o uso impessoal, o comentário de uma jornalista (ênfase minha):

> Difícil de entrar isso na cabeça, é tão certo para mim: ***tinham muitas pessoas*** no clube...

Comment: Bem, que ótimo que não sou o único a preferir a forma impessoal! Obs.: O primeiro link não está funcionando.

Comment: @marcus Consertei o link.

Comment: É relativamente fácil perceber como é errôneo usar Tem, basta perguntar-se: "quem tem?"
Aí nota-se a importância de usar Há ou Existem, que dá o sentido correto.

Answer (score 0):

O verbo haver, no sentido de existir, é impessoal. Dessa forma, ele não possui sujeito e se mantem no singular, no entanto, nem sempre essa situação é verdadeira! Algumas vezes, o verbo pode atuar como a um verbo auxiliar o que o torna sinônimo de "ter" em tempos compostos.

Exemplo:

Eles haviam chegado cedo

Eles tinham chegado cedo

Comment: Me desculpe pela franqueza, mas não isso não responde a pergunta (ou a intenção era só fazer um comentário?)

Comment: Para fazer comentários em outras respostas necessito de ao menos de 50 ptos de reputação. Então escrevi aqui!

Comment: Ah, entendi. Também acho estranho isso de restringir comentários.